# Android aapt output format

Tags: android, apk, aapt

What is the output format of the aapt?

for example check the output here http://elinux.org/Android_aapt

> config 0 lang=-- cnt=-- orien=0 touch=0 density=def key=0 infl=0 nav=0 w=0 h=0 sz=0 lng=0
>
> resource 0x7f040000 com.android.spare_parts:xml/spare_parts: t=0x03 d=0x00000003 (s=0x0008 r=0x00)

what does each field mean? is there any documentation or something?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/tools/aapt/Resource.cpp generates that, maybe you can figure it out in there.

Comment: Not very helpful, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses the second line of your example, aapt dump's representation of a value defined in `resources.arsc`.

In your example, the resource with ID 0x7f04000 in package com.android.spare_parts is a string called spare_parts with a value defined at index 3 in the string table.

The line is formatted as follows:

```c
resource <resource ID> <package>:<type>/<name> t=<dataType> d=<data> (s=<size> r=<res0>)
```

`resource ID` is the [well known](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+resource+id) ID you find in R.java.

`package` is simply the package that this resource is defined in and will be the same for all the resources in the package.

`type` the resource's type, one of a number of strings defined elsewhere in the resource table

`name` the resource's name

`data` is the resource value, interpreted according to dataType (see below)

`size` is the size of the value struct (not of the value). Seems to always be 0x0008.

`res0` is [always](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h#229) 0x00.

`dataType` is one of the constants defined [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h#233):

```c
// Contains no data.
TYPE_NULL = 0x00,
// The 'data' holds a ResTable_ref, a reference to another resource
// table entry.
TYPE_REFERENCE = 0x01,
// The 'data' holds an attribute resource identifier.
TYPE_ATTRIBUTE = 0x02,
// The 'data' holds an index into the containing resource table's
// global value string pool.
TYPE_STRING = 0x03,
// The 'data' holds a single-precision floating point number.
TYPE_FLOAT = 0x04,
// The 'data' holds a complex number encoding a dimension value,
// such as "100in".
TYPE_DIMENSION = 0x05,
// The 'data' holds a complex number encoding a fraction of a
// container.
TYPE_FRACTION = 0x06,

// Beginning of integer flavors...
TYPE_FIRST_INT = 0x10,

// The 'data' is a raw integer value of the form n..n.
TYPE_INT_DEC = 0x10,
// The 'data' is a raw integer value of the form 0xn..n.
TYPE_INT_HEX = 0x11,
// The 'data' is either 0 or 1, for input "false" or "true" respectively.
TYPE_INT_BOOLEAN = 0x12,

// Beginning of color integer flavors...
TYPE_FIRST_COLOR_INT = 0x1c,

// The 'data' is a raw integer value of the form #aarrggbb.
TYPE_INT_COLOR_ARGB8 = 0x1c,
// The 'data' is a raw integer value of the form #rrggbb.
TYPE_INT_COLOR_RGB8 = 0x1d,
// The 'data' is a raw integer value of the form #argb.
TYPE_INT_COLOR_ARGB4 = 0x1e,
// The 'data' is a raw integer value of the form #rgb.
TYPE_INT_COLOR_RGB4 = 0x1f,

// ...end of integer flavors.
TYPE_LAST_COLOR_INT = 0x1f,

// ...end of integer flavors.
TYPE_LAST_INT = 0x1f
```